# Making my program into a java file that can be used on other computers

Tags: java, text, executable, prompt

This is what I have

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reader {

```
    static int spc_count = -1;
    public static int count =0;



    public static void Process(File aFile) {
            spc_count++;
            String spcaces = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < spc_count; i++)
                    spcaces += " ";
            if (aFile.isFile() && aFile.getName().contains("mp3")) {
                    System.out.println(spcaces + "[FILE] " + aFile.getName());
                    count++;
            }

            else if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println(spcaces + "[FOLDER NAME] " + aFile.getName());
                    File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();
                    if (listOfFiles != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
                                    Process(listOfFiles[i]);
                    } else {
                            System.out.println(spcaces + " [ACCESS DENIED]");
                    }
            }
            spc_count--;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out
                            .println("Please enter the directory path ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String Directory = scanner.nextLine();
            File aFile = new File(Directory);
            Process(aFile);
            System.out.println("\n" + Reader.count+ " MP3 files were found in this directory.");

    }
```

}
What I want to do is to make it into a java file that I will be able to share with my friends and I would like it to prompt the user with a window to enter the directory and then display the output in a text file. I don't know if this is the best way to do this but any tips or suggestions on how to approach this would be appreciated.

Edit:
Yes I want to create a executable jar file but I was having complications when creating a GUI.
The problem that I had was when I wanted to output the name of the file to a text. What would be the best way to create a text file and have it show up when the code runs?

Comment: Unrelated, but two things: 1.) `Reader` is the name of an abstract class defined in `java.io`, so you should add a package declaration at the top of your file, and 2.) you import `java.awt.Font` but never use it.

Comment: It already *is* a Java file, so can you be more specific about what it is you want? Are you looking for a way to compile it, or something else?

Comment: I was going to suggest using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  But since your application has no GUI, it is not suited to launch by JWS!  2 notes: 1) That source is short enough to post direct to the site. 2) An app. with no GUI?  What millennium is this?

Comment: @Andrew you're kidding about not having a GUI, right?

Comment: @Rafe If you consider the CLI to be a GUI, then it has one.  I don't.  Either way, JWS cannot launch an app. designed to be run from the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Create [an executable jar](http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html).

Or even better (but a bit more work) you can distribute your app via [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html).

Comment: If the end-user double-clicks a Jar that is supposed to work from the command line, they will see no I/O.  For the same reason this app. is not suited to distribution using JWS.

Comment: Well, I didn't mention anything about clicking on a jar. +1 regarding JWS and IO.  Simple enough to open an AWT or Swing window.  (It is not a major production ..)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the program with [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) and distribute the resulting executable.